# Unable to run 2 dependent commands in the same whenever cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, cron-task, whenever, sitemap-generator-gem

I work on a Rails based website for which I have to create a sitemap using the `sitemap_generator` gem.

So far so good, until I reached the part where I have to automate the sitemap generation.
The 2 commands that I need to run in order to refresh the sitemap are `direnv allow && rake sitemap:refresh`.

I am trying to create a cron job by using the `whenever` gem and this is what I have inside `config/schedule.rb`:

```
# config/schedule.rb

set :output, "tmp/cron.log"
set :environment, "development"

every 1.minutes do
    command "/Users/<user>/<project>/generate_sitemap.sh"
end
```

The `generate_sitemap.sh` file is in the project root and has the following content:

```
# generate_sitemap.sh
#!/bin/bash

direnv allow
rake sitemap:refresh
```

In order to activate the cron job, I execute `whenever --update-crontab` in the terminal. By running `crontab -l`, I have the following output:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/<user>/<project>/config/schedule.rb at: 2022-01-27 18:51:18 +0200
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/Users/<user>/<project>/generate_sitemap.sh >> tmp/cron.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/<user>/<project>/config/schedule.rb at: 2022-01-27 18:51:18 +0200
```

I have to mention that if I execute `./generate_sitemap.sh` from the command line, it works. Furthermore, if I create a cron job as follows:
`config/schedule.rb`:

```
# config/schedule.rb

set :output, "tmp/cron.log"
set :environment, "development"

every 1.minutes do
    rake "sitemap:refresh"
end
```

it is executed, but it results into an error since `direnv allow` was not executed beforehand.

**My question is:** how can I create a cron job which executes both `direnv allow` and `rake sitemap:refresh`?

Comment: have you tried putting the commands on one line in the script file, like so ```direnv allow
&&  rake sitemap:refresh```

Comment: @dbugger
Yes, I tried. No difference